# Typescript: create an empty 2D array and insert values in it afterwards on different places

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, dom

I would like to create an empty 2D array. I know the size of the array, this gets dynamically decided. After the creation I want to insert different DOM objects inside this 2D array on dynamically created arraylocations. It says cannot set property of undefined. Did I do something wrong with the array initialisation?

```
let gridArrayNumbers = [];
      section.Layout.forEach(layout => {
        gridArrayNumbers.push(layout);//finallyhis , tarray will contain {2,3}
      });
      let gridArray: any [][] = [];

...

let e = document.createElement("label");
            e.textContent = element.content;             
            gridArray[element.layout.row][element.layout.column] = e;//throws the error here of undefined
```

Comment: can u paste the full error message ?

Comment: Unless this example is missing some code, `gridArray` is an empty array, so `gridArray[element.layout.row][element.layout.column]` isn't going to work

Comment: Is there a way to add elements on chosen positions like you said that won't work? Like initializing the array on some kind of way? I know the length for both 2D arrays but that did not help either... @user184994

Comment: `core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`, the 0 property is a value that I know.  @VikhyathMaiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you're doing

```
gridArray[element.layout.row][element.layout.column] = e
```

Won't work because the array is empty. You need to initialize the values first:

```
gridArray[element.layout.row] = []
gridArray[element.layout.row][element.layout.column] = e
```